# How do i use my jquery array in php code in same file

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am retrieving json from controller and want to use this json data in php file
just Want to use jQuery GETGEN array in php in this same file

```
$.ajax({
                url: '<?php echo site_url("movies/input/") ?>' + '/' + movie_id,
                type: 'post',
                data: "id=" + movie_id,
                dataType: 'json',
                beforeSend: function() {
                    $('.content').html('<div class="loader"><img src="<?php echo base_url("assets/images/loader.gif"); ?>"/></div>');
                },
                success: function(result) {
                    //console.log(result);
                    $("#id").val(result['movie_id']);
                    $("#title").val(result['title']);
                    var gen = result['genre'];
                    var getgen = gen.split(',');

                    $("#producer").val(result['producer']);
                    $("#director").val(result['director']);
                    $("#writer").val(result['writer']);
                    $("#music").val(result['music']);


                },
                error: function(jqXHR, status, error) {
                    if (status !== 'error')
                        alert(error);
                }
            });
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate the requirement

Comment: Where is your jquery array? Oh..ok I assume you want to use the `result` array inside your php code?

Comment: var gen = result['genre'];

Comment: it gives me an array which i want to use in my php foreach loop

Comment: you shouldnt use php and javascript in the same file... otherwise ajax is useless anyway :D

Answer (score 0):

there is no direct way because php execute at server side first and javascript run on client side.

but there is a way to use this array,

as your code shows this array is coming from server response, so before sending data from server, save it in session variable and you can use your session variable at server side

hope this help